# How can i make a view to always keep all data unless explicitly flushed?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using `Ionic v1`. I have contact list, every time i visit the view i have to load and render contacts again.

Whenever i go to a view and come back it will lose all `$scope` data its states. How can i make a view to always keep all data unless explicitly flushed?

I was going through `cache-view` http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ but nothing found

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your loaded contact list into a factory, so that you don't have load contacts again and again.

https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services